# model ensemble with shared layers

Tags: keras, keras-layer

In keras, I want to train an ensemble of models that share some layers. They are of the following form:

x ---> f(x)  ---> g_1(f(x))

x ---> f(x)  ---> g_2(f(x))

...

x ---> f(x)  ---> g_n(f(x))

here f(x) are some nontrivial shared layers.  g_1 through g_n have their specific parameters.

At each training stage, data x, is fed into one of the n networks, say, the i-th. A loss on g_i(f(x)) is then minimized/decreased via gradient based optimizer. How could I define and train such a model?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily do so by using functional Model.

A small example .. you can build on it:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input

X = np.empty(shape=(1000,100))
Y1 = np.empty(shape=(1000))
Y2 = np.empty(shape=(1000,2))
Y3 = np.empty(shape=(1000,3))

inp = Input(shape=(100,))
dense_f1 = Dense(50)
dense_f2 = Dense(20)

f = dense_f2(dense_f1(inp))

dense_g1 = Dense(1)
g1 = dense_g1(f)

dense_g2 = Dense(2)
g2 = dense_g2(f)

dense_g3 = Dense(3)
g3 = dense_g3(f)


model = Model([inp], [g1, g2, g3])
model.compile(loss=['mse', 'binary_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy'], optimizer='rmsprop')

model.summary()

model.fit([X], [Y1, Y2, Y3], nb_epoch=10)
```

**Edit:**

Based on your comments, you can always make different models and write the training loop yourself based on how you need your training. You can see in the `model.summary()` all the models are sharing the initial layers. Here is the extension to the example

```
model1 = Model(inp, g1)
model1.compile(loss=['mse'], optimizer='rmsprop')
model2 = Model(inp, g2)
model2.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy'], optimizer='rmsprop')
model3 = Model(inp, g3)
model3.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy'], optimizer='rmsprop')
model1.summary()
model2.summary()
model3.summary()

batch_size = 10
nb_epoch=10
n_batches = X.shape[0]/batch_size


for iepoch in range(nb_epoch):
    for ibatch in range(n_batches):
        x_batch = X[ibatch*batch_size:(ibatch+1)*batch_size]
        if ibatch%3==0:
            y_batch = Y1[ibatch*batch_size:(ibatch+1)*batch_size]
            model1.train_on_batch(x_batch, y_batch)      
        elif ibatch%3==1:
            y_batch = Y2[ibatch*batch_size:(ibatch+1)*batch_size]
            model2.train_on_batch(x_batch, y_batch)      
        else:
            y_batch = Y3[ibatch*batch_size:(ibatch+1)*batch_size]
            model3.train_on_batch(x_batch, y_batch)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It is helpful but still does not fully solve the problem. 

In your example, I want each minibatch of X to be pushed though only one of the three pipelines. In other words, there is a indicator variable that select one of the three losses.

Comment: Updated according to the comment.

Comment: This is great job! Thanks very much! Another concern: I believe train_on_batch() merely takes an SGD step, without using fancier optimization techniques, e.g., momentum SGD. Would it be possible to instead call model_i.fit(x_batch_i, y_batch_i, optimizer='fancier optimizer'), where i=1,2,3. My concern in this case is that: do these three separate calls share the same internal optimizer state (e.g., velocity of momentum SGD) for the parameters in function f? It seems to me that sharing these state is how optimization should be done.

Comment: 1) For SGD momentum: `sgd = SGD(momentum=0.1)` and then `optimizer=sgd` ... by default momentum is not enabled.  2) `train_on_batch()` will update the internal variables according to the rules set BUT each models have the optimizers separate and the internal variables are not shared among the optimizers. If you need so, you need to fall back on the previous snippet of code with one model having common optimizer and then you can use `compile(...., loss_weights=[1,0,0])` and write another callback class to change the `loss_weights` based on batches. It will become a bit tricky though.

Comment: Following your suggestion, to enable varying loss_weights, should I re-compile the existing model with a different loss_weights? Callback, as I understand (may be wrong), is to check the internal model state or do a customized validation during training. It cannot change a compiled model, right?

Comment: here https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L483-L640 in `compile` the `total_loss` is calculated which is used by `_make_train_function()` to get the update rule for the graph(at #L720-L722). Now using callback (https://keras.io/callbacks/#create-a-callback) in `on_batch_begin()` based on the batch, recalculate `self.model.total_loss` and set `self.model.train_function = None`.  Note: inside callback class to reference into model you have to use  `self.model.**`. And to understand callback you can check `_fit_loop()`

Comment: It could be a solution. However, the drawback is if there are lots of branches, but only one of them is active for a minibatch, then lots of computation are wasted. I find using tensorflow may be a better choice. Here is a relevant post
http://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/07/multi-task-learning-tensorflow-part-1.html

Comment: So, there, the optimizer states in the alternating training case are not shared?

Comment: For research work tensorflow will always be better as you can have more control. But the example in the link has the same solution as I have posted with Keras. When the losses are separate there are 2 diff optimizers `Y1_op` and `Y2_op` which is the 2nd solution whereas when the loss is combined then `session.run([Optimiser, Joint_Loss]..`  is called which is the 1st solution.

Comment: Thanks very much! This clarifies.

Comment: I was wondering if I can implement the same network @indraforyou suggested with graph model (with three input and three out puts). Although there is only one input in this case, but I am dealing with multiple inputs. Would there be any difference with graph model? --Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mohammadreza ya you can easily use multiple inputs. Check `merge` layers at https://keras.io/layers/merge/

Comment: Thanks for the answer @indraforyou. But the merge would mathematically add or concatenate the inputs. What I mean is something like this: X_1-->f(X_1)--> g_1(f(X_1)) and X_2-->f(X_2)--> g_2(f(X_2)). In which f is shared and g_1 and g_2 are task-specific layers.

Comment: Not sure why you need something like this, but you can easily modify the above example to get what you want, instead of one input there will be 2 inputs applying the same function.

Comment: Thanks @indraforyou. I am trying to implement a multi-task learning in which the data come from two sources. Each source is fed to the shared layer and then each task has its own dense layers to calculate the specific loss. I had implemented everything in one Graph model with two input and two outputs and I saw your solution that can capture the same thing but with two models instead of one. So I went ahead and modified your example for accepting two inputs. And both approaches work now. I was just wondering what is the difference of these two approaches. I appreciate if you share any idea.